# Error when trying to display errors with RubyOnRails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm seeing error:

> "undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass"

trying to display errors when creating a new user with a form. I'm a beginner with RoR so I have no idea where the error could come from. Here is my code:

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_current_user

  def create
    @user = User.create firstName: params[:firstName], lastName: params[:lastName], email: params[:email], password: params[:password]
    if @user
      @current_user = User.where(email: params[:email], password: params[:password]).first
      session[:user_id] = @current_user.id
      flash[:info] = "Vous etes maintenant connecte"
      redirect_to "/users/home"
    else
      render 'signup'
    end
  end

  private

  def set_current_user
    if session[:user_id]
      @current_user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    end
  end
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  validates :firstName, presence: {
    message: "Vous avez oublie quelque chose."
  }

  validates :lastName, presence: {
    message: "Vous avez oublie quelque chose."
  }

  validates :email, presence: {
    message: "Vous avez oublie quelque chose."
  }

  validates :password, presence: {
    message: "Vous avez oublie quelque chose."
  }

  validates :email, uniqueness: {
    message: "Cet adresse email est deja prise."
  }
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'users/home' => 'users#home'
  get 'users/login' => 'users#login'
  get 'users/signup'
  post 'users/login' => 'users#check'
  post 'users/signup' => 'users#create'
  delete 'users/login' => 'users#logout'
end
```

signup.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag "/users/signup", method: "post" do %>
  <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" />
  <p><%= @user.errors[:firstName].first %></p>
  <!-- More fields here -->
  <input type="submit" value="Confirmer" />
<% end %>
```

I saw this error appear on StackOverflow before but none of the answers applied to my problem :/ Thanks in advance for reading this and taking the time to help me!

Comment: Yohan, I recommend you install `byebug` (https://rubyplus.com/articles/3631-Debugging-using-ByeBug-Gem-in-Rails-5) to pause your application and debug in realtime

Comment: Can you show the server log?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error `undefined method errors for nil:NilClass` means you are trying to call `errors` on something that is nil. In this case, it is `@user` that is nil. You need to make `@user` available in the view...

In your routes add a controller action to get signup (this is not really necessary if the controller/action have the same name, but for others reading this it may be useful...

```
get 'users/signup', to: 'users#signup'
```

In your controller add a new method that instantiates a user

```
def signup
  @user = User.new
end
```

This should get rid of the error you are receiving...but there are other issues with your implementation (i.e. you should also follow vol7ron's advice and use strong params)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the exact reason, but you may need to whitelist your params:

```
## Inside your controller
## this may not be necessary, but demonstrates how to call a function before action
# before_action :user_params

## controller actions here
# ...

def create
  @user = User.create(user_params)
  # ...
end   

private

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:firstName, :lastName, :email, :password)
end
```

Comment: The error seems less complicated ahah but I got this as soon as I tried it: "wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 1)"

Comment: @Yohan `User.create(whitelist_params)` and remove the `before_action` line

Comment: @Yohan see the new edit.. I don't know your fields or what your form looks like, so maybe that will be enough?

Comment: My code for my form should be in my original post, and I tried to change what you told me to and I'm still getting the error about my `<p><%= @user.errors[:firstName].first %></p>`

Comment: It does unfortunately :/

Comment: The names of your form inputs should include the model.  For instance `type="text" name="user[firstName]"`, but it also might help you to use a form generator to simplify since you're learning.  This plays into why `require(:user)` was used followed by the permitted user fields (e.g., `.permit(:firstName)`).  I think the `user[firstName]` is necessary on your form input.